# Lex/Yacc Hash not Matching

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I'm trying to build a hash for variables in lex+yacc.  Lex receives a variable token and runs a hash function against yytext.  The return is stored in yylval.  I then access that value with $1 in my assignment and var rules.  I've made a parse tree for parsing, and a list of structs for my variables (structs allow for multiple variable types).  I can create a variable as expected, but the hash it receives in yacc is not the same one that it outputs in lex, this value is not the same as the one used when trying to access the variable later.  I am a novice with C and my head is spinning, so I'm wondering if anyone can look at the code below and see where I am going wrong.

lex file

```
#include "lee#.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

/* prototypes */
long removeQuotes(char* str);
int doHash(char* name);
%}

%%
[ \t\n\r        ]                  {}
[0123456789]+                      yylval = atoi( yytext ); return INT;
\"([^"]+)\"                        yylval = (long)removeQuotes(yytext); return STRING;
false                              yylval = 0; return BOOL;
true                               yylval = 1; return BOOL;
load                               return LOAD;
run                                return RUN;
print                              return PRINT;
printl                             return PRINTL;
printf                             return PRINTF;
loops                              return LOOPS;
then                               return THEN;
else                               return ELSE;
break                              return BREAK;
[;]                                return LINEEND;
kys                                exit(-1);
debug                              return DEBUG;
[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*                   yylval = doHash(yytext); return VAR;
.                                  return (int) yytext[0];
%%

int yywrap(void)
{
  return 1;
}

long removeQuotes(char* str)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; str[i]!='\0'; i++){
        str[i-1] = str[i];
    }
    str[i-2] = '\0';

    return (long)str;
}

int doHash(char* name)
{
    int i;
    int val=0;

    for (i = 0; name[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        val += (int) name[i];
    }
    printf("doHash: %d\n", val);
    return val;
}
```

yacc file

````
/* Lee# doesn't indicate the intellect of its creator, but it does sound a lot like C#. */

%{
#define YYSTYPE int
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

/* global variable */
long varsi[256];
char *varss[256];
int varsb[256];
char *names[256];
int types[256];
int varCount;
int null = 0;

/* parse tree */
/* 3 nodes because no stmt in grammar has more than 3 non-terminals */
typedef struct node node;    /*allows you to create a type with an alias*/
struct node
{
    int token;
    long val;
    node* ptr1;
    node* ptr2;
    node* ptr3;
};

/* prototypes */
void yyerror (char* s);
int yylex(void);
long makeNode(int token, long val, long p1, long p2, long p3);
long makeStr(long str);
long makeInt(int val);
long makeBool(int val);
void assignVar(long hash, long val);
long getVar(long hash);
int getVarDebug(long id);
void storeVar(long id, long val);
void cleanUp(node* tree);
void systemError(char* str);
void computeStmt(node* tree);
void runStatement(long ptr);

typedef struct decl decl;
struct decl {
    int kind;
    int iVal;
    char* str;
    int boolean;
};

typedef struct vartype vartype;
struct vartype {
    long hash;
    char* name;
    long val;
};
vartype vars[256];
%}

/* BISON Declarations */

%start lees  /* what rule starts */

%token CODE
%token LINEEND
%token INT
%token PRINT
%token VAR
%token BOOL
%token STRING
%token FALSE
%token TRUE
%token STR
%token TOINT
%token TOSTR
%token ASSIGN
%token ASSIGNPLUS
%token ASSIGNMINUS
%token ASSIGNDIVIDE
%token ASSIGNMULTIPLY
%token LOAD
%token RUN
%token PRINTL
%token PRINTF
%token LOOPS
%token THEN
%token ELSE
%token THENELSE
%token BREAK
%token DEBUG
%token GT
%token LT
%token EQ
%token LTEQ
%token GTEQ
%token NEQ
%token AND
%token OR
%token MINUS
%token PLUS
%token MULT
%token DIV
%token MOD
%token VAL
%token EXPRESSION

%left '-' '+' /* these done for precdence */
%left '*' '/' '('
%right '^' ')'   /* exponentiation        */



/* Grammar follows */
%%
lees:       code                                         { exit(0);           }
;

code:       line code
          | line
;
line:       statement LINEEND                       { runStatement($1); }
;

statement:  '{' code '}'
          | PRINT expression                             { $$ = makeNode(PRINT, null, $2, null, null); }
          | PRINTL expression                            { $$ = makeNode(PRINTL, null, $2, null, null); }
          | PRINTF val STRING                            { $$ = makeNode(PRINTF, null, $2, $3, null); }
          | expression LOOPS statement                   { $$ = makeNode(LOOPS, null, $1, $3, null); }
          | expression THEN statement                    { $$ = makeNode(THEN, null, $1, $3, null); }
          | expression THEN statement ELSE statement     { $$ = makeNode(THENELSE, null, $1, $3, $5); }
          | DEBUG var                                    { $$ = makeNode(DEBUG, null, $2, null, null); }
          | var '=' val                                  { $$ = makeNode(ASSIGN, $1, null, $3, null); }
          | var '+' '=' val                              { $$ = makeNode(ASSIGNPLUS, null, $1, $3, null); }
          | var '-' '=' val                              { $$ = makeNode(ASSIGNMINUS, null, $1, $3, null); }
          | var '*' '=' val                              { $$ = makeNode(ASSIGNMULTIPLY, null, $1, $3, null); }
          | var '/' '=' val                              { $$ = makeNode(ASSIGNDIVIDE, null, $1, $3, null); }
          | val                                          { $$ = makeNode(VAL, null, $1, null, null); }
          | RUN '(' val ')'                              { $$ = makeNode(RUN, null, $3, null, null); }
          | BREAK                                        { $$ = makeNode(BREAK, null, null, null, null); }
;

/* Could move operators to an operator section */
expression:      '(' expression ')'                                    { $$ = makeNode(EXPRESSION, null, $2, null, null); }
               | expression '+' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(PLUS, null, $1, $3, null);    }
               | expression '-' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(MINUS, null, $1, $3, null);   }
               | expression '*' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(MULT, null, $1, $3, null);    }
               | expression '/' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(DIV, null, $1, $3, null);     }
               | expression '%' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(MOD, null, $1, $3, null); }
               | expression '=' '=' expression                         { $$ = makeNode(EQ, null, $1, $4, null); }
               | expression '>' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(GT, null, $1, $3, null); }
               | expression '<' expression                             { $$ = makeNode(LT, null, $1, $3, null); }
               | expression '>' '=' expression                         { $$ = makeNode(GTEQ, null, $1, $4, null); }
               | expression '<' '=' expression                         { $$ = makeNode(LTEQ, null, $1, $4, null); }
               | expression '!' '=' expression                         { $$ = makeNode(NEQ, null, $1, $4, null); }
               | expression '&' '&' expression                           { $$ = makeNode(AND, null, $1, $4, null); }
               | expression '|' '|' expression                            { $$ = makeNode(OR, null, $1, $4, null); }
               | val                                     { $$ = makeNode(VAL, null, $1, null, null);   }
               | TOINT expression                               { $$ = makeNode(TOINT, null, $2, null, null);  }
               | TOSTR expression                               { $$ = makeNode(TOSTR, null, $2, null, null);  }
;

val:        INT                                          { $$ = makeNode(INT, makeInt($1), null, null, null); }
          | STRING                                       { $$ = makeNode(STRING, makeStr($1), null, null, null); }
          | BOOL                                         { $$ = makeNode(BOOL, makeBool($1), null, null, null); }
          | var                                          { $$ = makeNode(VAR, $1, null, null, null); }
          | expression                                   { $$ = makeNode(EXPRESSION, null, $1, null, null); }
;
var:        VAR                                          { $$ = makeNode(VAR, $1, null, null, null); }
;

%%

int main ()
{
  int i;

  varCount = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    vars[i].hash = -1;
  }
  yyparse ();
}

/* create a node for parse tree */
long makeNode(int token, long val, long p1, long p2, long p3)
{
    node* myNode;
    
    myNode = (node*)malloc( sizeof(node) );
    myNode->token = token;
    myNode->val = val;
    myNode->ptr1 = (node*)p1;
    myNode->ptr2 = (node*)p2;
    myNode->ptr3 = (node*)p3;
    
    return (long)myNode;
}

long makeStr(long str){
    decl* node;
    
    node = malloc( sizeof(decl) );
    node->kind = STRING;
    node->str = (char*)str;

    return (long)node;
}

long makeInt(int val){
    decl* node;
    
    node = malloc( sizeof(decl)) ;
    node->kind = INT;
    node->iVal = val;
    
    return (long)node;
}

long makeBool(int val){
    decl* node;
    
    
    node = malloc( sizeof(decl)) ;
    node->kind = BOOL;
    node->boolean = val;
    return (long)node;
}

void yyerror (char *s)  /* Called by yyparse on error */
{
  printf ("%s\n", s);
}


void assignVar(long var, long val)
{
    //node* hasht = (node*)var;
    //long hash = hasht->val;
    int target = -1;
    
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 256){
        if (vars[j].hash == -1){
            target = j;
            break;
        }
        else if (vars[j].hash == var){
            target = j;
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (target == -1){
        systemError("evalStmt (can't assign more vars)");
    }
    vars[target].hash = var;
    vars[target].val = val;
    printf("%ld\n", vars[target].hash);
}


long getVar(long hash)
{
    int k = 0;
    int target = -1;
    while (k<256){
        if (vars[k].hash == (long)hash){
            target = k;
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if (target == -1){
        systemError("getVar (can't find var with that hash)");
    }
    
    return vars[target].val;
}

/* evaluates VAL */
long evalVal(node* tree)
{
    int val;
    switch(tree->token)
    {
        case VAR:
            printf("evalVal->getVar: %ld\n", tree->val);
            return getVar((long)tree->val);
        case INT:
            return tree->val;
        case STRING:
            return tree->val;
        case BOOL:
            return tree->val;
        case EXPRESSION:
            // do something
        default:
            systemError("evalVal");
    }
}```

I didn't include everything from the yacc file because it is over 600 lines long, but I can include it all if necessary.  Let me know if you spot anything.
````

Comment: You have a problem: you have declared `YYSTYPE` to be `int`, but most of your rules assume that the semantic values like `$$` are compatible with `struct node *`.

Comment: `int`s and pointers are not even the same size on modern 64 bit platforms where we have 32 bit `int` and 64 bit pointers.

Comment: Your hashing strategy assumes that there are no collisions; you assume that if the hash matches, you have the correct variable.  When the hashes match, you have to compare the variable names to double check you don't have a false positive.

Comment: In a Yacc grammar, typically the `YYSTYPE` is a union defined via `%union`. The names of the members of the union become `%type` names for the grammar symbols, whose types are declared.   The `%union` becomes a C union. If you don't have a `%union`, then `YYSTYPE` defaults to `int`, like what you're expicitly doing, and all the semantic values in the grammar are of type `int`: all the `$1`, `$2` ... and `$$`.

Comment: I'm keeping the collision-prone strategy for now because it is simple to use while I get this working.  Would changing yystype to long help?